# CameraX preview not showing anything when front camera is selected

Tags: android, kotlin, camera, android-architecture-components, android-jetpack

I am trying to use CameraX library to capture image using front camera. But when the camera is launched, preview is showing nothing but black screen. Here is the configurations:

```
val previewConfig = PreviewConfig.Builder().apply {
            setTargetResolution(Size(640, 480))
            setLensFacing(CameraX.LensFacing.FRONT)
        }.build()

        preview = Preview(previewConfig)

        preview.setOnPreviewOutputUpdateListener {
            val parent = viewFinder.parent as ViewGroup
            parent.removeView(viewFinder)
            parent.addView(viewFinder, 0)

            viewFinder.surfaceTexture = it.surfaceTexture
            updateTransform()
        }

        val imageCaptureConfig = ImageCaptureConfig.Builder()
            .apply {
                setCaptureMode(ImageCapture.CaptureMode.MIN_LATENCY)
            }.build()

        imageCapture = ImageCapture(imageCaptureConfig)

        val analyzerConfig = ImageAnalysisConfig.Builder().apply {
            setImageReaderMode(
                ImageAnalysis.ImageReaderMode.ACQUIRE_LATEST_IMAGE)
        }.build()

        analyzerUseCase = ImageAnalysis(analyzerConfig).apply {
            setAnalyzer(executor, LuminosityAnalyzer())
        }
        CameraX.bindToLifecycle(this, preview, imageCapture)
```

But it's working well with `setLensFacing(CameraX.LensFacing.BACK)`. Also if i remove ImageCapture object from bindToLifeCyle method, i can see a preview with the front facing camera.

`CameraX.bindToLifecycle(this, preview, /*imageCapture*/)`

Please advise.

Comment: did you get to solve this?

Comment: I am facing the same issue, did you get any solution?

Answer (score 1):

You also need to set setLensFacing to front for imageCaptureConfig.
I was also facing the same issue , but your question solved my issue :p